# set datasource of gridview to a datatable without bind

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I am seting a datasource of a dataGridview to a table.
First In Load Event

```
Datagridview.datasource=DTFromSQl
```

In some Random Event I do.

```
Dim Dt as datatable=DataGridview1.datasource
```

When I do `DT.rows.clear()` it also clears the rows in the Datagridview. I suppose its due to databinding. But how is the databind occuring? and how to remove it so that changes in `DT` occurs in it only.

Thanks

---

Ok I did it but, something doesnt feel right about it.

```
Dim DTSend As New DataTable

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        DTSend.Columns.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name)
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code. when you will clear the `datatable` it will not clear your `datagridview`

```
 Dim dtsend As DataTable

 dtsend = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).Copy()

 dtsend.Clear()
```